# Using jQuery to change hidden field value based on select value

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change a hidden form value based on what the user selects from a drop down menu.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#color").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "black" ) {
        $("#id").val("21");
    } else if ($(this).val() == "white" ) {
        $("#id").val("22");
    }
});
```

Here is my form html:

```
<form class="addToCart" id="addToCart" name="addToCart" action="/cart/add">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="21">
    <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="Tank Top">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><span class="pink-font">Color</span></td>
            <td align="center"><span class="pink-font">Size</span></td>
            <td align="center"><span class="pink-font">Qty</span></td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <select id="color" name="color">
                    <option value="black" selected="selected">Black</option>
                    <option value="white">White</option>
                </select>
            </td>
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction. I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Works [fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/L5VqF/) (albeit it a little refactored)--is there more to this?

Comment: Works fine man: http://jsfiddle.net/yZneA/ `:)`

Comment: Have you put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})` ?

Comment: You can also try the `attr()` and `prop()` functions. Though, `val()` must work too.

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing jQuery right? Your code works fine.

Comment: How are you checking to see whether this has worked?

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers. I checked what Tats_innit had on fiddle and adjusted my code accordingly. It's getting late I guess, LOL. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I went with:

```
$(function() {
    $("#color").change(function() {
        if (this.value == "black") {
            $("#id").val("21");
        } else if (this.value == "white") {
            $("#id").val("22");
        }
    });
});
```